# Drawing hair, joining up all of the segments correctly

Tags: adobe-illustrator

In illustrator:

I have the following drawing, drawn with the pen tool.

[image]

The problem is that i drew each hair segment separately to be able to fill them separately, but redrew over lines in order to do that. Is there a way to merge these lines together and still maintain the ability to fill the strands in separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Make sure that all of the edges of your strands overlap (so that there are no 'gaps' between them) – the more they overlap, the easier this will be. Simply select the anchor points of your bottom strands and move them behind the top ones.
2. Select all of the strands, and in the **Pathfinder panel** click `Divide` – this will create a whole heap of shapes, including the areas where your strands overlap.
3. Now, select each strand *and* the overlaping areas you wish to include in the strand, and in the Pathfinder panel click `Unite`.

It's a bit of a hacky workaround, but it should do the trick.

Otherwise, if you don't mind your strands overlapping, you could probably get away with just doing Step 1.